# Adding key/values pairs to JSON map down one level

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to dynamically add new key/value pairs to an existing json map using jquery/javascript. An example of my structure is as follows:

```
var widgetTypes = {
  "CLASS_A": {
    "A1": "A1 Description",
    "A2": "A2 Description"
  },
  "CLASS_B": {
    "B1": "B1 Description",
    "B2": "B2 Description"
  }
};
```

How do I append a key/value pair to either class (i.e. CLASS_A or CLASS_B). For example, how would I add item A3 with description "A3 Description" to the CLASS_A section of the structure so that I then had the following?

```
var widgetTypes = {
  "CLASS_A": {
    "A1": "A1 Description",
    "A2": "A2 Description"
    "A3": "A3 Description"
  },
  "CLASS_B": {
    "B1": "B1 Description",
    "B2": "B2 Description"
  }
};
```

I know you can do something like widgetTypes['CLASS_A'].type = 'A3' etc. but I can't seem to get it quite right (or I'm way off the track). I found a lot of examples of adding items the level above (i.e. adding a CLASS_C) but nothing for what I'm interested in doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways:

1. `.` Dot notation.
2. `[]` Bracket notation.
3. `Object.defineProperty()` method.

---

```
var widgetTypes = {
  "CLASS_A": {
    "A1": "A1 Description",
    "A2": "A2 Description"
  },
  "CLASS_B": {
    "B1": "B1 Description",
    "B2": "B2 Description"
  }
};
```

### 1.

```
widgetTypes.CLASS_A.A3 = "A3 Description"
```

### 2.

```
widgetTypes["CLASS_A"]["A3"] = "A3 Description"
```

### 3.

```
Object.defineProperty(widgetTypes.CLASS_A, 'A3', {
  value: "A3 Description",
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
```

Option 3 has several other advantages over the two that you can configure the property behavior.

Answer (score 3):

```
widgetTypes.CLASS_A.A3 = "A3 Description";
```

or equivalently

```
widgetTypes["CLASS_A"]["A3"] = "A3 Description";
```

Comment: Thanks Amadan, that worked great. I knew it would be something simple like this.